# Addition box appears while using display: inline-block; HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

Addition box appears while using display: inline-block; HTML CSS, this is within an ul li a tag on CSS, unsure how to get rid of the extra box it creates, creating another li tag causes another box to appear instead of filling the empty one.

Link of the issue:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJ5TI.jpg
Link of the code:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIcSb.jpg

CSS:

```
nav{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
text-align: center;
background-color:black;
width: 800px;
height: 50px;
}

nav ul{
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0px;
padding: 10px;
}

nav ul li {
display: inline;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

nav ul li a{
background-color: white;
color: black;
display: inline-block;
width: 100px;
height: 20px;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 5px;
font-family: Arial;
margin: 0 auto;
border-radius:99px 99px 99px 99px;
width: 25%;
float: left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li><a href='index.html'>Home</a>
<li><a href='about.html'>About<a>
<li><a href='contact.html'>Contact</a>
<li><a href='http://www.uroulette.com/visit/ootrwu' target='_blank'>Random</a>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you show us at least your nav block html code? And pasting your code as text would help if someone would like to fiddle with it.

Comment: @Mr_KoKa done adding

Comment: On the about link, you are missing a slash `/`. And you should also close the `li` tags

Comment: @pol i hate myself

Answer (score 0):

You have not closed `<a>` tag at About, at end of the line there should be `</a>` instead of `<a>`. So instead of closing tag you made additional one.

Answer (score 0):

As @Mr_KoKa pointed out you're not closing the `a` tag also you're not closing any `li` tags

```
<ul>
  <li><a href='index.html'>Home</a></li>
  <li><a href='about.html'>About</a></li>
  <li><a href='contact.html'>Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href='http://www.uroulette.com/visit/ootrwu' target='_blank'>Random</a></li>
</ul>
```